# Keep getting '...is blocked because of many connection' on Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-rds

I'm finding that for the second time in a week I've got the '...is blocked because of many connection' issue with my Amazon RDS. From the monitor within RDS control panel I can see that I'm nowhere near the limit for max connections (it peaked at 25 and my instance can handle 2900).

Originally I had persistent connections turned on in my codeigniter app but after the first downage I turned it off. The app is hosted on a 1and1 dedicated server and connects remotely to Amazon RDS. Any insight would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

EDIT - I suppose another question I'm asking here is will upping my max_connect_errors help in any way?

Comment: Maybe you have been DDOS attacked...

Comment: If that were the case, could I expect to have seen a huge spike in connections? Is there a way I could investigate?